# select with range filter : pass selected value in function

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Here's my code :

```
<div ng-repeat="typeCircuit in vm.parent.getGestionCircuitDocument().listerTypeCircuits()">
    <select ng-options="n for n in [] | range:11" ng-model="newObject[typeCircuit.guid]" ng-change="vm.basculerTypeCircuit(typeCircuit, n)"></select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to display a select which contains 0,1,2...10 and when user select a value, I try to call the basculerTypeCircuit() function, and pass the typeCircuit and the selected number in the corresponding select.
This doesn't work, i always get "undefined" for n in my controller.

What do I miss?

Comment: i think u need to pass this "newObject[typeCircuit.guid]" instead of n

Comment: Oh yeah you're right thanks :)

Comment: is that working???

Comment: yup this is working ^^ (but i'll rename my var ^^)

Comment: you need not pass that variable in ng-change. All you can do is that define a variable in controller and bind it with ng-model, and then you can use that variable in "basculerTypeCircuit()" function. That can help you :)